# WordPress DMS plugins/software?

Tags: file-management, document-management, wordpress

Using latest and greatest of WordPress. We have a large team that keeps their training documents on our server. However one of the things that WordPress does natively really bad is sort media. As you know everything gets dumped into a monthly folder.

I would like to have something that allowed each user to have their own folder or have each page have the ability to have its own folder.  Really trying to replicate some of the Windows type sorting.  So we might have "Tech" classes that are sorted by 20 products and each product might have 20 classes.  Trying to break up the documents so that people can find them.

Also looking for more advanced features like putting fields on docs but that is just a bonus since I could add this myself.  And then even better if I could manage revisions of documents, doc search (PDF/Word parsing), and so on.

Let me know if this question should be broken up but maybe there is one thing that does it all.

Comment: Attachments are just posts of the type `attachment`. You can there easily just add a custom taxonomy and "tag" your attachments. Also you can just filter, using `pre_get_posts` the media screen so the query runs only on attachments a user uploaded themselves.

Comment: @kaiser - I understand the post type reference and I could use that to display but that is just a small part of the equation.  I have lots of people uploading media and this ranges from request forms to trainers uploading guides to editors uploading pictures and what not.

Comment: But why is the filesystem structure important? If it's really important, then rename the files during upload and prepend the users ID. This makes a `grep` or running a PHP `FilesystemIterator` or `RecursiveDirectorIterator` in combination with a `FilterIterator` extremely easy and ships as PHP SPL core default.